# differential equation with cosine

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am finding hard solving the following differential equation:

$$x\cdot \cos\left(\frac{y(x)}{x}\right)\cdot y'(x)+x-y(x)\cdot \cos\left(\frac{y(x)}{x}\right)=0$$

I found that the result is $y(x)=-x\arcsin(\log(x)-c_1)$ but I do not know the steps.

Comment: Since you claim not to know the steps as to solve the equation, you clearly "found that the result is ..... " by reviewing the solution.  That doesn't count as "effort" you've shown to actually solve the equation.  Second, what exactly are you "finding hard solving the DE"?  Third, you have not asked a question!

Comment: The question is obvious, how to solve this de. As for the result that i gave, it was generated by an online calculator.

Comment: Sometimes doing math *is* hard.  And sometimes, the best kind of learning is one for which you've struggled with some time.  That's part of the learning curve.  You've not shown any effort to understand, on your own behalf. Essentially, you're asking us to do *your problem* **for you**.  That's not appropriate here.

Comment: I will try the hint below to see if it works. If it works, in the future if i see a de ill know if it needs a change of variable. Also from now on, ill bare in mind that i can use change of variable to solve de(especially change it at the beggining) and not only use standard ways to solve a de(like bernulli's de). In this way i think that i expand my mind. I understand what u are trying to say, you are right and ofcourse i respect it. Anyway i dont know if you can understand what i am trying to say. Maybe i did not express my problem correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT :

Change of function : $\quad  y=x*u(x)$

This will transform the ODE to an ODE of "separable" kind, easy to solve.